# Inserting "String" variable inside a given String in C

Tags: c, string, path

I have a function, which has a String Parameter:

```
function(char str[3]){
 //here i want to insert the string Parameter str
 f = open("/d1/d2/d3/test"+str+"/d2.xyz")
}
```

I am trying to "insert" the String parameter into the given String path. How can I do this in C?

Comment: Research `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,  "/d1/d2/d3/test%s/d2.xyz", str)`.

Comment: Note that although the argument definition (`char str[3]`) suggests that the string is limited to 2 characters plus null, this is not enforced.  The parameter is treated as if you'd written `char *str` and any length could be provided — including zero bytes of string.

Comment: why is it limited to 2 chars? isnt it a char array like:  [0,1,2,3] ?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way would be to create a new string by piecing together the three pieces. One way do to this would be the following (shamelessly stolen from the @chux comment):

```
char buf[1000];
sprintf(buf, “/d1/d2/d3/test%s/d2.xyz”, str);
```

But before you go that route you need to ensure you really understand the printf family of functions as they are a common source of security related errors. For example, my buf size is large enough for your example, but certainly not for a general solution. Instead the sizes of the input strings would need to be taken into account to ensure the output buffer is large enough.

Comment: This would also fail if str is not properly null-terminated.

Comment: Point of nomenclature: it isn't a string if it isn't null terminated — by definition of what a string is (C11 [§7.1.1 Definitions of terms](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1): _A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character._ ) There is no such thing as a string that is not null terminated.  There are arrays of bytes that are not null terminated but should be.

Comment: Note my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243301/inserting-string-variable-inside-a-given-string-in-c#comment93372318_53243301).  As a consequence, it would likely be better to use `snprintf()` and check that the result was not clipped (and decide what to do about it).  Or use some sort of variable length memory allocation — a VLA (variable length array) or dynamic allocation via `malloc()` et al.

Comment: what does "null-terminated" mean?